# dynamic swf videos in Angular

Tags: node.js, flash, mean-stack

i have a problem with angular 
i am using a mean(node and angular) to make an application
the main goal is to prevent the download(using swf)
in the app:

a user can buy videos(swf to prevent the download)
a user can only watch a video he Bought

my problem is how to read it from angular side
i know i am getting data from server cuz if i take the blob and open it in an other window it works but i would like to put the video in an object or embed to make a video player

```
student:{name:'',videos:[{path:'c:/Temp/1.swf',name:'1.swf'},{path:'c:/Temp/2.swf',name:'2.swf'}]}
```

in this example I have one user to make it simple, has 3 videos that he Bought
i would like to send to the client side dynamecly one of the videos

node js:

```
.post('/get_swf', function (req, res) {
mongoose.model('student').findOne({}).exec(function(err,user){
        fs.readFile(user.videos[0].path, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(400);
                res.end("" + err);
                return;
            }
            res.writeHead(200, {
                "content-type": "application/x-shockwave-flash",
                "Content-Disposition": "attachment;
                filename="+user.videos[0].name
            });
            res.end(data);
        });
     })
    })
```

angular side

```
$scope.get_swf = function () {
                        $http.post('/api/get_swf', {}, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).then(function (data) {
                            console.log(data)
                            var swf_filee = new Blob([data.data], {type: 'application/x-shockwave-flash'});
                            var ur = URL.createObjectURL(swf_filee)
                            console.log(ur)
                            $scope.swf_file = ur
                        }, function (data) {
                        })
                    }
```

html:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="swf_file" > </embed>
```

Comment: Basically you want something like `<embed src = name_of_Blob_var >` maybe try `<embed src = swf_filee >` if you are using `var swf_filee` for actual blob data. I don't see how this method avoids downloading? They can still save the SWF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [receive data from flash and display on angularJS client side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846602/receive-data-from-flash-and-display-on-angularjs-client-side)